# How to check if particular string is present in variable with case sensitive and special characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, pattern-matching

I am having string this way,

"The save operation will overwrite [data] in DB;."

I am verifying this way to find is the above string is present in a particular variable.

```
var myVar  = "The save operation will overwrite [data] in DB;.";
                    var pattern = /The save operation will overwrite [data] in DB;./;
                    var exists = pattern.test(myVar);
                    alert(exists);
```

why even though pattern and string myVar is matached.. exists  is returning false only IN THIS CASE?

I want to exists = true if only if pattern string =='The save operation will overwrite [data] in DB;.'

for rest of all the cases exists should be = false.

ex: The save operation will update/overwrite [data] in DB;. should also return false.

Exist should be true  if and only if exactly this pattern is matched.
'The save operation will overwrite [data] in DB;.'

Where exactly I am doing mistake?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to escape the `[` and `]` and `.` for RegExp/ and if you're doing a direct match, it's much faster computationally  to compare strings.

Comment: @dandavis cant we do regexp with [] ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/589oj8sf/ You need to escape `\[` and `\]`

Comment: yes, just escape them with a backslash: `/hello \[data\]/`

Comment: Why are you using RegExp here?

Answer (score 1):

You are using pattern matching, and therfor you should escape special characters (http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html).

The correct syntax should be

```
var myVar  = "The save operation will overwrite [data] in DB;.";
                var pattern = /^The save operation will overwrite \[data\] in DB;\.$/;
                var exists = pattern.test(myVar);
                alert(exists);
```

Note the escape characters before '[', ']' and '.'. ALso the caret '^' tells the line should start there, and the dollar sign '$' the line should end there.

If you want to do case invariant, you can add 'i'. For multiple lines, add 'g'

```
var myVar  = "The save operation will overwrite [data] in DB;.";
                var pattern = /^The save operation will overwrite \[data\] in DB;\.$/gi;
                var exists = pattern.test(myVar);
                alert(exists);
```

You can use [this site](https://regex101.com/) to test regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions at all here, see below three "match" versions, use the one that fits your requirements:

```js
var myVar = 'The save operation will overwrite [data] in DB;.';
var pattern = 'The save operation will overwrite [data] in DB;.';

var exists = myVar.indexOf(pattern) > -1;
var startsWith = myVar.indexOf(pattern) == 0;
var strictEqual = myVar === pattern;

alert('Exists: ' + exists + '\n' + 
     'Starts with: ' + startsWith + '\n' + 
     'Strict equal: ' + strictEqual);
```

Comment: This won't work in DB replace `[data]` with single quote (')

Comment: @Imad - what won't work? the code *works*...  How is single quote at all relevant? I don't understand anything in your comment.